# Reading Input Stream and splitting based on a delimiter

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

I have a scenario where I will get a large data as an input stream, which is going to have a delimiter and split it and process them. I want to process , this completely in memory , if its possible. Right  now I am achieving this with the help of scanner as shown below , in the code:

```
package chap5_questions;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class paintjob_chp5 {

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class ScannerTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\Project\\Journalling\\docs\\readFile.txt"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(fin, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("--AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIaabbccdd");
            String theString = null;

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                theString = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(theString);
                functionToProcessStreams(theString); // This will actually do the processing.

            }

            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure, if this is the most efficient way to do this. Another thing that comes to mind, is to use the `read(b, off, len)` function on inputstream, and then process each of the bytearray. However, for this I need to know , the index of the delimiters , which might again be reading the entire stream.

Please, suggest if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Scanner` with `useDelimiter()` is efficient: it uses a (constructed) regular expression and will read your input only once.

On a side note: Even if it would cost a bit of efficiency, it is always a good idea to use legible code. This will allow you adapt your code faster and you will make less mistakes. Premature optimalization is the root of all evil.