# Spring batch break single line into multiple records

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have input flat file coming from a vendor. It has multiple records on a single line delimited with string "ST". Line starts with characters "STA" which marks start of the header and ends with a section which starts with string "GE". in summary format is -

```
<header record starting with STA>ST<record1>ST<record2>...<end of the line start with GE>
```

I would like read this line using Spring Batch, break down the records as if I'm reading them from separate lines and each should be formatted

```
<header record starting with STA>ST<record><end with section GE>
```

How should I write my FlatFileItemReader ?

I tried recordSeparatorAttribute on FlatFileItemReader class but that didn't help.

Thank you.

Comment: If the file is fairly big, I'd recommend using `Scanner` with delimiter and read lines, as explained in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047997/reading-input-stream-and-splitting-based-on-a-delimiter

Comment: No file won't be big. Thanks for sharing the link. I'm trying to find Spring Batch based solution because our batch job application which is supposed to read and process this file uses Spring Batch framework.

Comment: Did you find a solution? @sk2013